# Is it possible to use the status output of a GENIE 08 microcontroller as a digital output as well?

Tags: microcontroller, led, gpio

I have a GENIE 08 microcontroller, and am running low on available pins to use. Currently I am using pin 7 solely for status output, which is connected to the download socket. It can also be used for a digital output, so  would it be possible to connect an LED to it while the download socket is still in place? When I come to upload new code would it be an issue that the LED is drawing current from the pin?

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 digital output pins (G1-G4) available to user on GENIE 08 as per its datasheet at https://www.genieonline.com/files/genie-08-microcontroller.pdf. The G0 digital output is shared with Status output so if you have an LED at G0, it will only work depending upon the value on the status output line. The LED will draw current but if you are not controlling the G0 output pin from your program, having an LED at G0 shouldn't interfere with the functioning of the download socket.